# Why can I not get all my email sending stats from a Workmail address vs same address using SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications, amazon-sns, amazon-ses, amazon-workmail

I have an AWS Workmail account using admin@example.com.
Then I have an SES-verified email and domains admin@example.com and example.com

When I use a lambda function to send emails using SES from admin@example.com I get full, "delivered", "open", and "click" notifications via the SNS topic I am subscribed to.

However, when I use the Workmail web interface to send an email from the exact same address (admin@example.com) I don't get any notifications.

It's as if Workmail doesn't use the SES email address...

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Work mail uses a different sending mechanism than SES and doesn't include the SES " Click Tracking " you are referring to.

Workmail is more of a " day to day " and does not include these features

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm just confused about this because the docs say it does:

``Amazon Simple Email Service—Amazon WorkMail uses Amazon SES to send all outgoing email. The test mail domain and your domains are available for management in the Amazon SES console. There is no cost for outgoing email sent from Amazon WorkMail. For more information, see Amazon Simple Email Service Developer Guide.``

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/what_is.html

Comment: it uses SES to send but its meant to be more of a everyday mailbox, like using 365. so it won't append the tracking. SES only appends the tracking when you send via SES explicitly. At the moment to my knowledge there is no way to trigger the tracker headers on workmail.